# Nginx page not / 404 with Angular build bundle

Tags: angular, nginx

Angular bundle work, but if i go to another page, for example /cards, nginx return 404. Why?
Im using docker file for starting nginx, Angular app building with ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js build
I will search response in google, but config edit isnt help

nginx.conf

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name localhost;
 root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 index index.html index.htm;
 location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;\n\
 }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
...imports...

const appRoutes: Routes =[
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'cards', component: CardsComponent},
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RegistrationComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    PreloaderComponent,
    CardsComponent,
    CardComponent,
    CardTextPipe,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Dockerfile for building nginx

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY . ./usr/share/nginx/html
RUN echo "server {\n\
 listen 80;\n\
 server_name localhost;\n\
 root /usr/share/nginx/html;\n\
 index index.html index.htm;\n\
 location / {\n\
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;\n\
 }\n\
}" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
```

Comment: I don't see the command for install packages for your angular app in docker container. are you copying build folder in docker container using dockerfile?

Comment: Im using gitlab ci, angular app builds in other job and dist add in artifact. Build docker command: docker build -f docker/mtg-ladder_instances/dockerfiles/frontend.Dockerfile -t registry.gitlab.com/ignatinyutsin/mtg-ladder/frontend-compile:latest ./frontend/dist/frontend. This problem is not about angular, else / path isnt work

Comment: Ok. Did you tried with hash strategy in angular? But your url rewrite code is correct for nginx.

Comment: I'm not tried this strategy, problem is resolved, thank you too match

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolver, $uri in echo command like environments.